# how to update model for one combobox based on selection of another combobox?

Tags: sapui5

I have two sap.m.ComboBox in a table row. Items in second ComboBox varies on selction of first ComboBox. Following is the code i have written but its not refreshing the items in second ComboBox.

```
var firstCombo = new sap.m.ComboBox({items:[new sap.ui.core.Item({text:"EmployeeLevel4"}),
                                                new sap.ui.core.Item({text:"EmployeeLevel3"})],
                                             selectionChange : oController.comboBoxMapping});

var secondCombo = new sap.m.ComboBox("SecondComboBox",{});
```

> In Controller

```
comboBoxMapping:function(oEvent){
    var filterMappingModel = \\getting the model;
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("SecondComboBox").setModel(filterMappingModel);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("SecondComboBox").bindItems('/', new sap.ui.core.Item({key: '{Skill}',text: '{Skill}'}),true);
}
```

Suggest me some options to impelemet it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the `selectionChange` event handler of the first combo, you should set the `filter` of the `ContextBinding` of the `items` of the second combo. E.g.:

```
this.getView().byId("secondComboBox").getBinding("items").filter([
        new sap.ui.model.Filter(
                "CategoryID", 
                "EQ", 
                oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem").getKey())  
]);
```

To see this in action, have a look at [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/firopepolo/1/edit?html,output).

As mentioned in on of the responses to this answer, the examples above show only how to change the binding of a combobox. Since your comboboxes are embedded in a table you will first have to figure out which of the comboboxes needs to be changed as there are several in the table.

It would be my advice so look at oEvent.getSource(), which should result in the combo that has just been changed. From there, you could use getParent() to go up in the control hierarchy until you've reached the row. Within that row, you should have several columns, and one of those columns contains the SecondCombo box. If you know which row contains your SecondCombo, you will be able to get it using byId and set the filter as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Since OP mentioned the combo boxes are in a table, referencing them by ID won't work I'm afraid...

Comment: You're right. Completely overread that part. OP has to do a bit more work: getting retrieving the table rows and trying to find out which of the table rows contains the combobox she needs to set the filter to.

Comment: Yeah, too bad filtering based on bound data is not possible, see ancient issue https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/130